# WooCommerce subscriptions + PayPal issues

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm running an online store, which is offering a subscription based service using WooCommerce + Subscription plugin.

However, when somebody is purchasing a subscription, the actual Order ( under WooCommerce -> Orders ) is marked as Pending Payment, while the transaction itself is *successful* under the PayPal account. Therefore, I have to manually mark the payment as *completed*.

Have anyone had similar issues?

What I've checked so far:
1. PayPal configuration - it seems that everything is running smoothly
2. Subscriptions - the recurring payments are actually working.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

In this case , the root cause is of your PayPal IPN not working functionally.

Please refer the below link.

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/paypal-standard/#section-8

If above solution could not help you solve the issue, please contact woocommerce for further assistance.